# circular bullets are not displaying in html page

Tags: html, css, coldfusion

I am writing an un-ordered list in a html page. I have used css class for getting bullets for "li" tag. But bullets are not displaying, Instead horizontal lines are coming. I am writing html page in ColdFusion (.cfm) pages.

My html Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>Resource Optimization</title>

<META NAME="resource-type" CONTENT="document">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="DEPT: RESOURCE Optimization: Index">
<META NAME="KeyWords" CONTENT="Departments, Index, DEPT, Resource, Management, North, Generation, Report, Reports, OATI, On, Line, Tagging, Daily, Gas, Totals, Energy, Marketing, Purchase, Sales, Schedule, Schedules, Pricing, Pathing, Optimization">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="Intranet Contruction Crew for Sierra Pacific Resources">
<META NAME="Reply-to" CONTENT="dtheiss@nevp.com">
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="ColdFusion Studio 4.0">
<META NAME="Copyright" CONTENT="2000 Sierra Pacific Resources">

<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-style-type" CONTENT="text/css">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-language" CONTENT="en-US">
<style type="text/css">
ul.list{
list-style-type:circle;
}
</style>

</head>

<cfinclude template="/matrix_nav_top_full_min.cfm"><br> 

<!--- <body> --->
<div id="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-inner">       
                <div class="page-container" >
                <!--- <cfinclude template="/matrix_nav_top_full.cfm"> --->
                <!-------Resource Management DEPARTMENT INDEX PAGE---------->
                <font style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 10pt;">
                <div align="right" style="background-color:FFFFFF; "><strong>Keyword: RM</strong></div>
                <div align="left" style="background-color:FFFFFF; ">
                <!---LOKI 17129 &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/dept/Graphics/title_resourceMgmt.jpg" width="480" height="40" border="0" alt="Resource Management Department">--->
                <!--- LOKI 19816&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/dept/Graphics/title_resourceProcurementOpt.jpg" width="99%" border="0" alt="Resource Procurement and Optimization">--->
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/dept/Graphics/title_resourceOptimization.jpg" width="98%" border="0" alt="Resource Optimization">
                <hr size="3">
                <br>
                <strong>Departmental Areas:</strong>
                <ul class="list">
                <li><a href="/DEPT/RM/gas/index.htm">Gas Optimization</a>
                <li><a href="/DEPT/RM/MarketPrices/index.htm">Market Prices</a>
                <li><a href="/DEPT/RM/Reports/index.htm">Reports</a>
                <li><a href="/DEPT/RM/STA/index.htm">Short-Term Analysis</a>
                <li><a href="/DEPT/RM/RMN/index.htm">Short-Term Optimization</a>
                <li><a href="/DEPT/RM/TMA/index.htm">Transaction and Market Analysis</a>
                </ul>
                <br><br>
                <!--- <cfinclude template="/new_footer.cfm"> --->
                </div>
                </div>

<cfinclude template="/new_footer_rd_min.cfm">                       
<!--- </body>
</html> --->
```

I am getting a page like below.
[image: My Unordered list]

How can I get Bullets in li.

Comment: can you show the css?

Comment: I created a fiddle with the provided HTML and the bullets seem to appear. http://jsfiddle.net/f99n2/. I guess the problem with your styles, could you please provide any CSS code selecting the ``li`` elements?

Comment: <style type="text/css">
ul.list{
list-style-type:circle;
}
</style>

Comment: I think we would need to see more than the list CSS to assist you more.

Comment: @SandeepReddyK. I guess it is not all the code, either provide a link or create a fiddle and paste there all the CSS code, that would help us more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<li>` elements naturally have a bullet beside them, however, you may have some other property overriding this making dashes showing up.

Add the proper list-style-type to force them back to bullets:

```
li{
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

---

This is not shown in your fiddle because no CSS is provided in your fiddle, so the fiddle will appear to be exactly the same. Note that the elements do have bullets beside them in [your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/f99n2/) If I apply the `list-style-type` to [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f99n2/1/), it still looks the same.

Comment: Thank you. Its working in IE8 and chrome. But it is not working in IE7.